# why loop/grouping not working correctly in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me why loop/grouping not working correctly in jquery

when I take data

```
var data = ['c', 'd', 'c', 'abc', 'dee', 'pu', 'gu'],
```

it work correctly
But when I take data

```
var data =  ["VADODARA", "AHMEDABAD"],
```

`VADODARA` should come inside `Q--z` here is my code

https://jsbin.com/zowibewema/edit?html,js,output

```
$(function(){
  var data =  ["VADODARA", "AHMEDABAD"],
    groups = ['A--D', 'E--I', 'J--P', 'Q--Z'],
    groupIndex = 0,
    result = '';

result += '<ul>';
result += '<li>' + groups[groupIndex] + '</li>';
data
    .sort()
    .forEach(function (s) {
        if (s[0].toLowerCase() > groups[groupIndex].slice(-1).toLowerCase()) {
            result += '<li>' + groups[++groupIndex] + '</li>';
        }
        result += '<li>' + s + '</li>';
    });
while (++groupIndex < groups.length) {
    result += '<li>' + groups[groupIndex] + '</li>';
}
result += '</ul>';
document.body.innerHTML += result;
})
```

Expected output

```
<ul>
    <li>A--D</li>
    <li>AHMEDABAD</li>
    <li>E--I</li>

    <li>J--P</li>
    <li>Q--Z</li>
    <li>VADODARA</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a while loop for getting all groups before the actual value.

```
while (s[0].toLowerCase() > groups[groupIndex].slice(-1).toLowerCase()) {
```

```js
var data = ["VADODARA", "AHMEDABAD"],
    groups = ['A--D', 'E--I', 'J--P', 'Q--Z'],
    groupIndex = 0,
    result = '';

result += '<ul>';
result += '<li>' + groups[groupIndex] + '</li>';
data
    .sort()
    .forEach(function(s) {
        while (s[0].toLowerCase() > groups[groupIndex].slice(-1).toLowerCase()) {
            result += '<li>' + groups[++groupIndex] + '</li>';
        }
        result += '<li>' + s + '</li>';
    });
    while (++groupIndex < groups.length) {
        result += '<li>' + groups[groupIndex] + '</li>';
    }
result += '</ul>';
document.body.innerHTML += result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you sorting the array anyway, [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the `data` with the `groups`, and [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) everything. Iterate them both with [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and create the HTML string:

```js
$(function() {
  var data = ["VADODARA", "AHMEDABAD"],
    groups = ['A--D', 'E--I', 'J--P', 'Q--Z'],
    combined = data.concat(groups).sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.localeCompare(b);
    }),
    result = '';

  result += '<ul>';
  combined
    .forEach(function(s) {
      result += '<li>' + s + '</li>';
    });
  result += '</ul>';
  document.body.innerHTML += result;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```